# django + uwsgi + nginx subdomain for apps

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am using django + nginx + uwsgi following this tutorial http://blog.richard.do/index.php/2013/04/setting-up-nginx-django-uwsgi-a-tutorial-that-actually-works/ and it works for me.

now in my project i need subdomains for different apps with same database for example i have app1 and app2 which share same users.i need nginx direct urls to correct app i mean app1.example.com goes to app1 directly from nginx not from django after proccessing the url.can anyone give me the nginx.conf and uwsgi.ini configuraion and how to run them.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [django-subdomains](http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). From their docs:

If no `subdomain` argument is provided, the URL will be resolved relative to the `SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS[None]` or `ROOT_URLCONF`, in order

```
>>> from subdomains.utils import reverse
>>> reverse('home')
'http://example.com/'
>>> reverse('user-profile', kwargs={'username': 'ted'})
'http://example.com/users/ted/'
>>> reverse('home', scheme='https')
'https://example.com/'
```

For `subdomains`, the URL will be resolved relative to the `SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS[subdomain]` value if it exists, otherwise falling back to the `ROOT_URLCONF`:

```
>>> from subdomains.utils import reverse
>>> reverse('home', subdomain='api')
'http://api.example.com/'
>>> reverse('home', subdomain='wildcard')
'http://wildcard.example.com/'
>>> reverse('login', subdomain='wildcard')
'http://wildcard.example.com/login/'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I meant the nginx do the navigation work not django.i saw an example for apache but i couldn't use it on nginx